# Use of LB in base URL and shards parameter for search in Solr (ver: 6.1.0)

Tags: java, solr, solrj, solrcloud

We are using Solr 6.1.0. We have 2 shards and each has one replica with 7 zookeepers in our live environment.

Our **Solr URL** is
[http://solr2.xyz.com:8983/solr/actionscomments/select?q=+resource_id:(123)+and+entity_type:(4)++action_status:(0)++is_active:(true)+and+recipient_id:(5941841)&sort=action_date+desc,id+desc&start=0&rows=1000&fq=&fl=action_id&indent=off&shards.tolerant=true&shards=s3.xyz.com:8983/solr/actionscomments|s3r1.xyz.com:8983/solr/actionscomments,s4.xyz.com:8983/solr/actionscomments|s4r1.xyz.com:8983/solr/actionscomments](http://solr2.xyz.com:8983/solr/actionscomments/select?q=+resource_id:(123)+and+entity_type:(4)++action_status:(0)++is_active:(true)+and+recipient_id:(5941841)&sort=action_date+desc,id+desc&start=0&rows=1000&fq=&fl=action_id&indent=off&shards.tolerant=true&shards=s3.xyz.com:8983/solr/actionscomments%7Cs3r1.xyz.com:8983/solr/actionscomments,s4.xyz.com:8983/solr/actionscomments%7Cs4r1.xyz.com:8983/solr/actionscomments)

I would like to understand correct configuration for use of LB and shards parameters in URL. Above URL we use for search in collection.

Note: We have observed that after the LB configuration, we got intermittent slowness when load is very high. If we put IP instead of LB then we do not face intermittent slowness.

1. In current configuration base URL (https://solr2.xyz.com) is of LB which point to IPs of shards (Shard1 & Shard2) and replicas (replica1 & replica2). Is it correct? or instead provide IP of shard be more effective?
2. What is importance of shards parameters? What should we use in shards parameters LB URL or direct IP of shards and replicas?

Comment: If you're using cloud mode - why are you using an additional loadbalancer in front of your nodes? The Solr client should be able to connect directly to the nodes that have the replicas for the collection you're interested in by contacting zookeeper. This is handled automagically for you, and the `shards` parameter is an "old" relic for when you had to do manual sharding instead of using cloud mode.

Comment: @MatsLindh We are using additional loadbalancer in our base URL because we use search in traditional way like final DefaultHttpClient client = HttpClientFactory.getTimeoutingClient(timeout);
client.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
final HttpPost request = new HttpPost();
URIBuilder uri = new URIBuilder(url);
request.setURI(uri.build());
final HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(request, new BasicHttpContext());

Can you suggest me client code for searching in Solr via Zookeeper instead of HttpPost

Comment: You'd use the CloudSolrClient instead, giving it the addresses of your zk nodes: https://solr.apache.org/docs/8_8_0/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/CloudSolrClient.html  - Your other option is to stop using the `shard` parameter (it's not necessary when using solr cloud), and instead add all Solr nodes as destination nodes. Solr will then route the requests internally. This will put additional load and network hops on your service, but might work good enough.